# java.net.URL giving security vulnerability during code scan

Tags: java, security, url

I have the below method to check an incoming url is valid or not and based on this i need to redirect to error page.

```
/*
 * This method is used to validate the URL and return a response
 */
private static int isValidUrl(String qrUrl) {
    int code = 0;
     try {
            URL url = new URL(qrUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.connect();
            code = connection.getResponseCode();  
            logger.info("Response code is {} for the url", code);
        } catch(MalformedURLException e) {
            logger.error("A MalformedURLException Occured in QR Code servlet during URL Validation", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("An IOException Occured in QR Code servlet during URL Validation", e);
        } 
    return code;
    

}
```

The below line of code is giving medium security vulnerability(Description:
This web server request could be used by an attacker to expose internal services and filesystem) during code scan. How can I fix it?

Comment: The fix is simple in principle - don't attempt to open URLs that are provided by an external user or possible attacker. To give a more specific answer, we'd need to know more about what you're actually doing and why/how you need the URL validated.

Comment: Do you really need to call the URL? For generating a QR code (qualified guess) is it not enough to know that the format is correct? If so, simply create the new URL and see if you get a MalformedURLException or not. If you do need to call the service you must take care that you don't trust anyone with giving you the URLs... It is a security risk. EDIT: if you really must call, at least make sure it is a http/https URL and not file or something.